# Is there a Windows 7 64-bit printer driver out there for the Tally T2024/24 dot matrix printer?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, drivers, printer

Is there a Windows 7 64-bit printer driver out there for the Tally T2024/24 dot matrix printer?

I've looked all over the place for the right driver, but it's got me stumped!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I don't know this printer at all, but have you tried to use a generic Epson ESC/P printer driver? That's kind of working for many dot matrix printers like Star or NEC.

Answer (score 1):

This isnt a direct answer to your question, but maybe it will help.

W7 appears to have a very limited supply of default printer drivers, unlike XP which seems to have very many.  To obtain many additional drivers, begin installing the printer, when it asks for the printer driver click 'use windows update' and see if that helps.  The result should be that W7 connects and downloads lots of printer drivers (you will be able to see these new drivers in the selection window)...and hopefully it will download one for your printer or one that will work.

Also, I have had luck recently using drivers for similar printers or even the generic text only driver in some cases.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @cop1152.  Unfortunately, this device driver isn't in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/), so the "use windows update" button doesn't find it :(.  I've since tried the Epson LQ-300 driver with limited success.